# Where are cookies of Firefox stored in windows?

Tags: browser, cookies

Is there a place to check all the cookies so far?

Comment: Apart from HTTP cookies, plug-ins might have their own cookie-like mechanism, like the cross-browser "Flash-cookies" -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object#File_locations

Answer (score 9):

They are in an SQLite database in the "Application Data" folder. On my Windows 7 system:

```
C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\g47mlt1n.default\cookies.sqlite
```

Answer (score 2):

In Windows XP

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[user_name]\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile_name].default\cookies.sqlite
```

Cookies are saved SQLite DB format

Answer (score 1):

There is a place to look at the cookies Firefox has in the options window. In Firefox 3.6, under "Tools", "Options..." and in the "Privacy" tab, there is a section about cookies with a button labeled "Show Cookies". You can see the cookies organized by site, search them, and see details about them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have firefox [webdeveloper toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60), I highly recommend it in case you don't.

Simply go to the bar,click cookies, and view cookie information. It's much better than going through the actual files

Comment: Is that any different from the standard Firefox Cookie window?