# Backup and restore cookies in Firefox

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, firefox, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are cookies of Firefox stored in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/121729/where-are-cookies-of-firefox-stored-in-windows)

How would I go about backing up and restoring cookie files for Firefox on an Windows XP install (EDIT: within a batch script)?

I have a maintenance script that runs, and there are select users that save passwords into their browser for auto-logins. I would like to delete all of the other cookie entries from the list, then backup the remaining cookies, and have that file restored everytime the maintenance is ran.

If I understand correctly, Firefox puts its cookies into an SQLITE database?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [url](http://www.ghidinelli.com/2009/04/15/recover-corrupted-firefox-cookies-sqlite) which is for recovering corrupted firefox cookies. However, with a little or no modification you can use that to create the backup of cookies and restore the same.

Comment: I would, except the URL doesn't load =(

Comment: Are you referring to the link I mentioned? I can still load it without any trouble. May be it is only you, try some proxy like kroxy.net .

Comment: could be our network filter running its magic on that url =/ . I'll check it out at home later.

Comment: @sparx.me This is why we don't like 'link only' answers here on SU, in case the link dies/doesn't work in the future.  Perhaps consider editing you answer and including an extraction of the pertinent info from the link you are providing.

Comment: Thank you for the note techie007. However, I really hesitate to copy paste the whole answer from an external link. Thats why I added the link directly instead.