# Where are cookies are stored in Iceweasel on Linux?

Tags: linux, iceweasel

My question is similar to

- [Where are cookies of Firefox stored in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/121729/where-are-cookies-of-firefox-stored-in-windows)

but, I am using Iceweasel (on Linux) which, supposedly, is almost the same as Firefox. 
Where are the cookies stored, how can they be read, etc? To find answers to such questions,

I looked for files that have the string "cookie" in their name. There are two such files in an inner subdirectory of my home directory, namely, cookies.sqlite and cookies.sqlite-journal. But the files can't be opened. Besides, I am not sure if these are really the files that uphold the cookies. Mind you, I also checked Edit > Preferences > Privacy. Still did not get what I am looking for.

I am hoping to get the location of the cookies, open them, possibly tamper with them, etc. Put simply, I am looking for any information that adds to my insight about cookies.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](http://www.cafewebmaster.com/howto-readexport-firefox-cookies-linux), Firefox cookies are stored in an SQLite database. Iceweasel is the same.

I found the database at:

```
/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/2bsy6m22.default/cookies.sqlite
```

I was able to open it using the Iceweasel extension [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) or using the [SQLite3 application](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That was very helpful.